# input type file to convert to drag and drop jquery object

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, input

I recently cobbled together some code that allows for a drag and drop file to be uploaded to my server via jquery. Now I am trying to add a form with an file selection input to use the same code. The problem is, I cant seem to get the file selection input to be read into a compatible object.

My drag and drop code essentially  has, on drop:

```
var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
```

I am then feeding the "files" variable into another function to handle the jquery/ajax upload.

When trying to get the file input selection to work in a similar fashion, I try this code, but have no luck:

```
var files = new FormData();
files.append("file", $("#fileselect")[0].files[0]);
```

## fileselect is the id for my

```
<input type="file" id="fileselect"></input>
```

But when i feed this "files" variable into the existing function, I cannot read properties such as:

```
console.log("file length: " + files.length);
```

Any tips on pointing me into the right direction? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This probably doesn't help. But there are already libraries that do this and are sexy. https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: ah, yes. There are a number of jquery file upload and drag n drop libraries. Since I already had some existing code and am fairly new to jquery stuff, I didn't want to break the existing work by trying to incorporate a third party. This way, my project only had the jquery library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to achieve the same format exactly, but since later functions were just assigning data to a FormData object, I copied that function and adjusted it some so I could translate the data pulled from a form input into a FormData object before proceeding with the rest of my code, then I could read the various properties with slightly different syntax before converting it into a FormData object and proceeding like normal:

```
var file = $("#fileselect")[0].files[0]; //read from file input
var filename = file.name;
var filesize = file.size; //in bytes
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', file);
```